# How to use tensorflow in pycharm?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, pycharm

I have installed `tensorflow` on my Ubuntu, I can import it from shell but I can't from pycharm. Here is my screen :

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: this is simple: your project name conflicts with package name

Comment: right! thank you. Write it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your project differently: now you are trying to import package `tensorflow` (your project) and use it inside of it.

Try to rename your working directory to `tensorflow_test` or something different than `tensorflow`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the python interpreter that PyCharm is using.

Go to `options->project->project` interpreter and select the correct one, most likely a virtualenv you created, where you installed tensorflow instead of the default.

Comment: look at picture, there is a same paths in the shell and in the python interpreter